# SwiftUI - RTL device languages don't display the expected RTL layout

Tags: ios, swiftui, padding, right-to-left

The following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding(.leading, 150)
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 16)
                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

looks like this when the system and app languages are set to a LTR language:

[image]

Oddly, if I set the device language to Arabic the layout is unchanged, it appears the same as English. The same problem if I set the app language to Arabic in "Edit scheme..." in Xcode.

However, if I set the app language to "Right-to-Left pseudolanguage" the layout is as expected for a RTL language:

[image]

Why is the expected RTL layout not shown when I set the device or app language to Arabic? How can I make my app display correctly on devices set to a RTL language?

Comment: Did you add arabic localization for that text? Did you activate arabic localization support at all?